# Реализация класса Buffer

Tags: классы, java

Доброго времени суток! при реализации подкласса класса Buffer, на конструкторе выдает такую ошибку:

```
Implicit super constructor Buffer() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
```

без конструктора выдает это:

```
Implicit super constructor Buffer() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

в чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у класса `Buffer` нет конструктора по умолчанию (без параметров), поэтому при создании экземпляра подкласса `Buffer` нужно явным образом вызывать конструктор класса `Buffer`. Тут есть ещё одна тонкость: у класса `Buffer` нет public-конструкторов. Есть только конструкторы уровня пакета. Такие конструкторы могут вызывать только классы, находящиеся в одно пакете с классом `Buffer`. Можно поместить ваш класс в пакет `java.nio`, но это плохое решение. Ведь если конструктор скрыли от пользователей, значит, им не нужно его явным образом вызывать. Пересмотрите свою архитектуру и подумайте, нужен ли вам наследник `Buffer`. Судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам, вам нужен экземпляр `Buffer`. Так как это абстрактный класс, то создать его экземпляр оператором `new` не получится. Но у него есть наследники. В частности, `ByteBuffer`. В нём есть статический метод `allocate()`, который создаёт экземпляр класса-наследника `Buffer`.

Comment: а не подскажете, как записать в его массив? ато я не нашел такого метода